# Are these two having the same meaning: 遥远的地方 vs. 远方

Tags: grammar, word-choice, vocabulary

遥远的地方 vs. 远方

Are these two having the same meaning?

Like these sentences:

我住在一个遥远的地方。

我住在远方。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- 远方 is more literary/ classical
- 遥远的地方 is more colloquial/ modern

我住在一个遥远的地方。= 'I live in a faraway place'

我住在远方。= 'I live in some faraway place'. We don't need the classifier 一个 for 远方, it is a term for 'far away place(s)' in general.